# How to get Mean and Covariance value from pomegranate Gaussian Mixture model

Tags: python, mixture-model, gmm, pomegranate

In the scikit learn Gaussian mixture model we can get mean and covariance by

```
clf = GaussianMixture(n_components=num_clusters, covariance_type="tied", init_params='kmeans')
for i in range(clf.n_components):
    cov=clf.covariances_[i]
    mean=clf.means_[i]
```

But in the case of  pomegranate Gaussian Mixture model says  **no attributes called 'covariances_' and 'means_'** 
Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `covariance_type="tied"`, the model assumes a common covariance matrix for all components, so the code above does not hold. If `covariance_type="tied"` then it will be 1 covariance matrix under clf.covariances_ . Refer to [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html):

> ‘full’ each component has its own general covariance matrix
>
> ‘tied’ all components share the same general covariance matrix

With `pomegranate` it estimates a covariance matrix for each component, so a good comparison with running `GaussianMixture` from sklearn with `covariance_type="full"`

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

iris = datasets.load_iris()

clf = GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type="full", init_params='kmeans')
clf.fit(iris.data)
cov = []
means = []
for i in range(clf.n_components):
    cov.append(clf.covariances_[i])
    means.append(clf.means_[i])
```

So for component or cluster 0 :

```
means[0]

array([5.006, 3.428, 1.462, 0.246])

cov[0]

array([[0.121765, 0.097232, 0.016028, 0.010124],
       [0.097232, 0.140817, 0.011464, 0.009112],
       [0.016028, 0.011464, 0.029557, 0.005948],
       [0.010124, 0.009112, 0.005948, 0.010885]])
```

Now using pomegranate:

```
from pomegranate import GeneralMixtureModel, MultivariateGaussianDistribution

mdl = GeneralMixtureModel.from_samples(MultivariateGaussianDistribution,
                                       n_components=3, X=iris.data)
mdl = mdl.fit(iris.data)
```

The parameters can be accessed under `distributions`, and you have a list as long as your components. For the first, you do `distributions[0]`, second `distributions[1]` and so on:

```
mdl.distributions[0].parameters[0]

[5.005999999999999, 3.4280000000000004, 1.462, 0.24599999999999986]

np.round(mdl.distributions[0].parameters[1],6)

array([[0.121764, 0.097232, 0.016028, 0.010124],
       [0.097232, 0.140816, 0.011464, 0.009112],
       [0.016028, 0.011464, 0.029556, 0.005948],
       [0.010124, 0.009112, 0.005948, 0.010884]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much @StupidWolf, I found the concept just now here : https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jmschr/lectures/pomegranate.html . But your explanation is just great, thank you agian

Comment: glad it worked you. Yes thats a very useful weblink. Thanks for sharing too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137982/how-to-assure-that-the-covariance-matrices-are-all-positive-definite-in-pomigran @StupidWolf